# IE9 doesn't compute width properly with floating elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, width, css-float

When I create say a div container with a say 100px width and place 2 div elements one floating to the left and the other to the right with a border of 2px and a width of 46px each they should be drawn on the same line side by side covering the whole width of the parent container. This happens in Firefox and Chrome but IE9 draws them on separate lines and in order to have the same effect as in the other browsers I need to specify a width of 102px in the parent element.
Why is that?

Here's the code:

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

div {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div style="border: 5px solid;width:100px;height:100px">

<div style='border:2px solid green;width:46px;height:46px;float:left'></div>

<div style='border:2px solid 
green;width:46px;height:46px;float:right'></div>
<div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add some code and maybe we can assist. By what you mentioned I can just tell you that the floating elements within your main div are overflowing which is why your divs are not being contained.

Comment: I can't see how two 56px width div can float side by side in a 100px div parent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a solution to the problem.

What you have to do is you have to add the Doctype declaration e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

It doesn't seem to be because of the ie box model bug http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug
As this behaviour would result in smaller elements...
I'm really confused...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd much rather use `display: inline-block` than much around with floats.

Anyway, the most likely cause of the problem is the empty whitespace between the two `<div>` elements. It could be shifting the second one down. Try removing it (ie. `<div...>...</div><div...>...</div>`)

Comment: All floats are block elements so they're not affected by whitespace as far as I know nonetheless I've removed all whitespace but I still face the same problem...